# SQL: create table with composite referencing primary key, and foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship, create-table

So I have the following ER diagram:
[image]

So Subthing is a generalization. Stuff is either made out of Metal or Wood, it can't be just a Subthing. Here's the create code:

```
CREATE TABLE Thing (
    ThingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Subthing (
    consists_of INTEGER REFERENCES Thing(ThingID),
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);

CREATE TABLE Wood (
    Wstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (SubthingID, consists_of) REFERENCES Subthing(SubthingID, consists_of),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);

CREATE TABLE Dust (
    DustID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Metal (
    Mstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    requires INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Dust(DustID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SubthingID, consists_of) REFERENCES Subthing(SubthingID, consists_of),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);
```

What I want is for Metal to, at the same time, have a primary key which references (SubthingID, consists_of) and a foreign key with requires, referencing DustID. I can't declare it as a foreign key after the fact since (SubthingID, consists_of) is already a foreign key. 
How could you solve this, other than making requires into a table?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was too stupid.

```
CREATE TABLE Metal (
    Mstuff VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    consists_of INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SubthingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    requires INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (requires) REFERENCES Dust(DustID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SubthingID, consists_of) REFERENCES Subthing(SubthingID,     consists_of),
    PRIMARY KEY (SubthingID, consists_of)
);
```

Works just fine.